# Removing characters in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I've been tasked with reading a text file and counting the wins of superbowl teams from 1967 to 1977. So far my program only prints the occurrences of each line and counts it as 1 because they all have different years attached to the team names. I don't know how to remove the years from the team names. So far I have

```
def word_count():
    city_list = []
        city_file = open('win_count.txt', 'r')
        for city in city_file:
            city = city.rstrip('\n')
            city = city.split('\n')
            city_list.append(city)
        my_dict = {}
        city_file.close()
        for item in city_list:
            for city in item:
                if city in my_dict:
                    my_dict[city] += 1
                    else:
                        my_dict[city] = 1
        print('city\t\tCount')
        for key, value in my_dict.items():
            print(key,'\t', ':' , '\t', value)
word_count()
```

This is the win_count.txt file

```
1977 Oakland
1976 Pittsburgh
1975 Pittsburgh
1974 Miami
1973 Miami
1972 Dallas
1971 Baltimore
1970 Kansas City
1969 New York Jets
1968 Green Bay
1967 Green Bay
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are confident with the format in which file data is written, you can split the city with space and just append city[1] into city_list.

The problem is here.

```
for city in city_file:
   city = city.rstrip('\n')
   city = city.split('\n') # Splitting with '\n' will give ["1971 Baltimore", '']
   city_list.append(city) # This appends the list obtained from previous step into city_list.
```

And here

```
my_dict = {}
city_file.close()
for item in city_list:
    for city in item:
        if city in my_dict: # Right way is to use my_dict.itervalues()
```

Try this version.

```
def word_count():
    city_list = []
    with open('win_count.txt', 'r') as city_file:
        temp_list = city_file.readlines()
        for item in temp_list:
            city = (item.rstrip('\n')).split(' ') #This gives you list of words like ['1971', 'Baltimore']
            city_list.append(city[1])
    my_dict = {}

    for item in city_list:
        if item in my_dict.itervalues():
            my_dict[item] += 1
        else:
            my_dict[item] = 1
    print('city\t\tCount')
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        print("{:10}\t{}".format(key,value))

word_count()
```

Comment: I tried what you said and it gave me a list of each character occurrence. It worked when I tried 'city_list.append(city[1:4])'

Answer (score 0):

If the begging of each row is just 4 characters for the year plus a space you can get city name with just `city_name = row[5:].rstrip('\n')`

```
def word_count():
    city_list = {}
    with open('win_count.txt', 'r') as city_file:
        for row in city_file:
            city_name = row[5:].rstrip('\n')

            if city_name in city_list:
                city_list[city_name] += 1
            else:
                city_list[city_name] = 1

    print('city\t\tCount')
    for key, value in city_list.items():
        print(key,'\t', ':' , '\t', value)

word_count()
```